# android videoview - managing bad urls error?

Tags: android, video, error-handling, android-videoview

Im using some time expiring url to watch a video from internet and so, when the expiration time come out, the video is not working anymore. In this case, im getting an error dialog box from the videoplayer saying the video is unreadable. that is quite fine, but i would like to display my own dialog box text. how can i do ? is there any way i can know my video didnt work ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer my self reading a bit more the SDK. There is setOnErrorListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener).

that you can create. :)